# casperjs check that title exists and has any value so test not empty

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs

This seems like an easy question but I am new to casperjs.

I want to check that title exists and that it has a value e.g. not ="". Also same for meta tags that they exist and also have been populated with something. I don't want a specific value just test they exist and not empty e.g. not ="".

I thought this would be simple in casperjs 1.1 test suite

*Site:*

```
<head>
    <title>UnoSpark</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation.css">

    <meta name="description" content="Free Dating WebSiteWeb">
    <meta name="keywords"    content="dating, love">
    <meta name="author"      content="Paul">
</head>
<body>
<div class="sharedWidget" data-widget="sharedWidget" data-widget-id="CMSHEADER">
```

*Tests:*

```
casper.test.begin('title test',2, function(test)
{
    var url = "http://www.unospark.com/";
    casper.start(url).then(function()
    {
    this.test.assert(this.getTitle()!='');
    this.test.assertDoesntExist('meta:empty');

    }).run(function()
    {
    test.done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run XUnit type tests with the `casper test script.js` command. Keep in mind that the `test` command uses an internal casper instance so you don't need to create one.

```
// script.js
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var url = "http://www.unospark.com/";
casper.test.begin('title test', function(test) {
    casper.start(url).then(function() {
        test.assert(this.getTitle()!=''); // straight forward
    }).run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});

casper.test.begin('meta test', function(test) {
    casper.start(url).then(function() {
        // The following selector tries to select 'meta' elements which are empty
        // This is achieved through the :empty CSS pseudo-class
        test.assertDoesntExist('meta[content=""]');
        // or using XPath
        test.assertDoesntExist(x('//meta[not(@content)]'));

        test.assertExists("*[data-widget-id='CMSHEADER']")
        // or as XPath but more general
        test.assertExists("//*[@*='CMSHEADER']")
    }).run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

It is probably a good idea to combine some tests into one method for performance reasons.

```
// script.js
var url = "http://www.unospark.com/";
casper.test.begin('header tests', function(test) {
    casper.start(url).then(function() {
        test.assert(this.getTitle()!='');
        test.assertDoesntExist('meta[content=""]');
    }).run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the brain fart. `meta` tags have their content in the attribute and not as a child. You could have said that something went wrong. The url must be complete, so [http://www.unospark.com/](http://www.unospark.com/).

Comment: Artjom B. sorry new to this. I managed to format code. The title works but I am confused with meta tags. I want test to pass if each meta tag has a value and fail if any are empty e.g. author in example

Comment: Yes, it now fails, but you have to manually fix this when a test turned up an error. You have to manually find the offending tag. Everything else seems overkill.

Comment: Artjom B but it fails even when all meta tags have a value so the test cannot be right

Comment: But I added value to Author so should not fail now. see updated meta tag author

Comment: I had a typo in `this.assert(this.getTitle()!='');`, it should have been `test.assert(this.getTitle()!='');`. Try now.

Comment: thanks but that doesnt explain why test fails on meta tags when all three have a value. e.g. when none are empty

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem as both of the tests pass. Just to be sure, you don't get the line `PASS Fail to find element matching selector: meta[content=""]`, which is correct.

Comment: Thanks I've fixed it another way.

Comment: How? You can add you own answer.

Comment: I am trying but it complains about formatting. you can prove yours doesnt work by having three meta tags each with a value and it still fails

Comment: Artjom B. Any idea how to test for CMSHEADER in the added section?

Comment: This will be a straight forward CSS selector. You should read up on that. The XPath selector is more generalised.

Answer (score 0):

```
    casper.test.begin('title test',4, function(test)
{
    var url = "http://www.unospark.com/";
    casper.start(url).then(function()
    {
        test.assert(this.getTitle()!='');
        test.assertExists('meta[name="description"]');
        test.assertExists('meta[name="keywords"]');
        test.assertExists('meta[name="author"]');

        descrip = this.evaluate(function()
        {
            return document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').content;
        });

        keywords = this.evaluate(function()
        {
            return document.querySelector('meta[name="keywords"]').content;
        });

        author = this.evaluate(function()
        {
            return document.querySelector('meta[name="author"]').content;
        });

        console.log("Meta " + descrip);
        console.log("Meta " + keywords);
        console.log("Meta " + author);

        test.assertNotEquals(descrip, "", "Meta description not empty");
        test.assertNotEquals(keywords,"", "Meta keywords not empty");
        test.assertNotEquals(author,  "", "Meta author not empty");


    }).run(function()
    {
        test.done();
    });
});
```