# CasperJSs Check text exists

Tags: testing, casperjs

I can check class exists but how do I check there is a data-widget-id of 'CMSHEADER'

```
<div class="sharedWidget" data-widget="sharedWidget" data-widget-id="CMSHEADER">
```

*Test:*

```
test.assertSelectorExists('.sharedWidget', "widget exists");
```

Comment: I added this to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23374998/1816580) already, you don't have to ask again.

Comment: I can get SharedWidget as it is a class but selector doesnt find data-widget-id hence the question. I want to find data-widget-id with a value of 'CMSHEADER'

Comment: Have you tried `*[data-widget-id='CMSHEADER']` as a selector?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
this.getElementAttribute('.sharedWidget', 'data-widget-id');
```

I answered a similar question few days ago...

And you can combine it with :

```
this.test.assertEquals(this.getElementAttribute('.sharedWidget', 'data-widget-id'), "CMSHEADER", "Value of attribute *data-widget-id* of class *sharedWidget* equals 'CMSHEADER'");
```

**Edit** : I may have misunderstood the question, like Artjom said, to select an element by its attribute :

```
this.test.assertExists('[attribute="value"]', "widget exists");
```

so for you indeed :

```
this.test.assertExists('[data-widget-id="CMSHEADER"]', "widget exists");
```

See : [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: the reason I couldnt find assertSelectorExists is because it isnt in casper documentation. The way to do it is test.assertExists('div[data-widget-id="CMSHEADER"]', "CMS Footer widget exists");

Comment: Yeah my bad, don't know why I've written selector.